# Time complexity of recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have a grid with **x**-sided field in it. Every field contains a link to it's **x** surrounding fields. [**x is constant**]

I have an algorithm which is implemented in this field, (which can probably be optimized):

[java like pseudocode]

```
public ArrayList getAllFields(ArrayList list) {

  list.addToList(this);

  for each side {
    if ( ! list.contains(neighbour) && constantTimeConditionsAreMet()) {
      neighbour.getAllFields(list) //Recursive call
    }
  }

  return list;

}
```

I'm having trouble finding the time complexity.

`ArrayList#contains(Object)` runs in linear time

How do i find the time complexity? My approach is this:

```
T(n) = O(1) + T(n-1) +
c(nbOfFieldsInArray - n) [The time to check the ever filling ArrayList]

T(n) = O(1) + T(n-1) + c*nbOfFieldsInArray - cn
```

Does this give me `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)`?

Comment: Where's the recursive call meant to happen?  Is 'getContinent' meant to be 'getAllFields'?

Comment: I put a comment in the code :)

Comment: Change the list to a hash table and you have an O(n) algorithm where n = number of fields :)

Comment: I was planning on doing that. Would you agree the algorithm is O(n^2) now?

Answer (score 2):

The comment you added to your code is not helpful. What does `getContinent` do?

In any case, since you're using a linear search (`ArrayList.contains`) for every potential addition to the list, then it looks like the complexity will be Omega(n^2).

Comment: Very sorry, i had named it differently before, i forgot i renamed it later and thanks; That's a hint already :)

Comment: +1: But to nitpick: 'at least O(n^2)' is not too meaningful. Perhaps you mean to say Omega(n^2)?

Comment: @Moron: noted. Although my reading of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations indicates that "Omega(n^2)" means "O larger than n^2", which (I thought) was the same as "at least O(n^2)". I can see, though, how my term is less informative.

Comment: @JIm: It is not 'less informative'. Technically speaking, it is  actually meaningless.

Comment: To be more clear: O(n^2) means not worse than cn^2: i.e. BigOh is used to state _upper_ bounds. So what you are saying is "at least not worse than cn^2". Omega is used to state lower bounds, which is _exactly_ what you need here...

Comment: Omega(n^2) is "larger than" O(n^2). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations. I have no idea about your T(n) formula. What is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

You recurrence seems correct `T(n) = T(n-1) + theta(1)`.

If you draw the recursion tree you'll notice you have a single branch with the values `theta(n-1), theta(n-2), ..., theta(2), theta(1)`, if you add up all the levels you get the [arithmetic series 1+2+3+...+n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

```
S1 = 1+2+3+...+n
```

If you define

```
S2 = n+...+3+2+1
```

and then calculate `S1+S2` you get

```
S1 + S2 = 2*S1 = (n+1) + (n+1) + ... + (n+1) = n(n+1)
```

therefore

```
2*S1 = n(n-1) => S1 = n(n-1)/2
```

which means `T(n) = 1/2 theta(n(n-1)) = 1/2 theta(n^2) = theta(n^2)`